# Moonlight hunt with trample

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I play [Moonlight Hunt](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMoonlight%20Hunt%5d), and my Werewolves have trample, does the excess damage from my creatures get applied to the player?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, trample only works when dealing combat damage. The damage dealt by creatures because of Moonlight Hunt is non-combat damage.

> **702.19a** Trample is a static ability that modifies the rules for assigning an attacking creature’s combat damage. The ability has no effect when a creature with trample is blocking or is dealing noncombat damage.